# What is a good member directory plugin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm working on a site for a local homeschool group, and they'd like to have a page(s) with a member directory on the site.  Any suggestions?  Something like the [Business Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/business-directory/) plugin would probably be great, just more focused on listing individuals.

Edit: I actually want a plugin that lets me create listings manually, as opposed to using the existing user/member list in WordPress.  That will work better in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, based on your requirements I'd suggest you consider just using [**Custom Post Types with custom fields**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187) and defining your own layout. That way you won't be painted in to the limitations of a plugin that doesn't meet you needs exactly, and it sounds like Custom Post Types will fit your requirement pretty much spot on. Here's [**another answer**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187) I previously wrote that give that discusses Custom Post Types.

In addition I'll point you to a 2nd answer I wrote where I described [**How to Recreate CrunchBase in WordPress using Custom Post Types**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/381/can-crunchbase-com-be-done-with-wordpress/386#386). After all, there is really very little technical implementation difference between creating a directory of companies and a directory of people, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that will create a member list:

- [Members list](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-list/)

Seems like a lot of admin to keep up to date though - good luck, I have seen a lot of things like this start great but then fall by the wayside.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited my original post to clarify that I'm looking for something to let me manually input users, as opposed to using the user database in WP.

Comment: I would be interested to know what solution you went with in the end?

Answer (score 0):

If all the people you want to display are already users of the WordPress site, you can use [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-users/) plugin to display the site's users.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited my original post to clarify that I'm looking for something to let me manually input users, as opposed to using the user database in WP.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly overkill for what you want but perhaps [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/) could be of use? I know of people using it in an eLearning context and it's got a lot to offer.

Comment: Unfortunately that would be overkill in this situation. Nice to know it is used in that context, though.  Maybe for another future project.