# Suggestions for Implementing a Wedding Website in WordPress?

Tags: customization

A would like to create a website in WordPress that allows user to create wedding websites. What suggestions can you give me on how to implement it?

Comment: This is how I did it:  www.debandtal.com   But it is pretty standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only got a minute to offer suggestions tonight but I thought I'd **quickly point you to two (2) other answers** here on this website that provide information you'll need. Much of what I'd suggest for your use-case is identical to what I recommended on these other answers:

- [**Tips for using WordPress as a CMS?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/)
- [**Implementing a CrunchBase.com Clone using WordPress?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/381/implementing-a-crunchbase-com-clone-using-wordpress/)

The other thing I can tell you is to look at **WordPress Multisite** as it will allow you to set up as many different websites on the same WordPress installation as you like. It's basically was [**WordPress.com**](http://wordpress.com) is running on.  Here are some articles that can explain it:

- [**How to Enable Multisite in WordPress 3.0**](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-enable-multi-site-option-in-wordpress-3-0/)
- [**How to Enable Multisite in WordPress 3.0**](http://wptheming.com/2010/03/wordpress-3-0-enable-network/) (video)
- [**WordPress 3.0 Walkthrough: Getting Started with Multisite**](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/06/02/wordpress-3-multisite/)
- [**Creating a Network**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) (the sites on a multisite installation are called a *"network"*)
- [**WordPress 3.0: Multisite Domain Mapping Tutorial**](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/)

Comment: Now what next, after enabling multisite, Can anyone please guide me through the rest of the process

Comment: Hi *@MsManiya:* It will help if you can provide more specific questions about each of the things you want to accomplish. The question *"How do I implemented a Wedding Site"* is too broad for us (or at least for me) to answer on one question here if you are looking for all the specific details required to implement the site. Divide and conquer!

Comment: Ok, I want the following features
• Password protected entry
• Assigning a subdomain
• Unlimited custom web pages
• Wedding Guestbook entries
•    Upload photos/video option
•    Personal Wedding blog options

Comment: the user will have the option of choosing templates from the given free templates or buy one, so i also want a payment option thing in my website

Comment: *@MsManila:* I was suggesting that you ask a complete question here on this site for **each** of the different things you want to accomplish, i.e. a new page on this site for each question. What you are currently asking for is for us to write a book for you on this one page! :-) I would also suggest you not ask too many questions at once so you can actually work on using the solutions that we give you to each question before you attempt to move on to the next question.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/wedding-website-accounts heres my first question please give your reply and thannks a lot for your sugestions :)

Comment: Hi *@MsManiya*: Thanks for creating new questions. For the next few days I don't have the time to follow up but I see others have. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Multisite is the answer. We have a lot of tools at [WPMU Dev Premium](http://premium.wpmudev.org) - including themes and plugins that will help you to offer memberships or paid upgrades for the sites created in your network.

You'll also probably want to create or hire someone to create a number of decent wedding type themes before you launch so that your users can select from among them, as many wedding sites offer this ability.