# Creating a searchable A-Z listing of hundreds of companies/services

Tags: customization, cms, directory

I am about to create a webbased guide. A guide that will list numerous of companies - their services, contact information and so on. And I need help coding this!

I am using Genesis News Child Theme and I want the following (have looked into Custom Post Types UI and taxonomies but need to develop this further!). It is all really quite straight forward - you are looking for a product/serviece, you need to be able to evaluate if you should contact this company, if yes, you want to know who to call, what they are offering you.

This is the information that need sto be POSSIBLE but not mandatory necessary to add to each post:

1. Company name (which should be listed as an A-Z list of companies
2. Company logo (I am thinking in the sidebar area but not necessary) linked to URL
3. Company text description
4. Company contact details (here it should be possible to add several contact persons - if there is one KAM for public sector, one for Production industry and so on)
5. TAGS - for what they are offering - these (or made in another way) need to be searchable. Let’s say that a company is looking for providers that sell a certain product/service, in a specific market, for their particular industry. This is key - how to make key word searchable  making it possible for users to search for a shortlist of about 10 perfect match companies among maybe houndreds!
6. Customer references (this could simply be links to PDF:s, but need to be shown visibly)
7. A list of features/functions that can be ”marked”/”unmarked” (these are commonly asked for features/functions) to help select a solution best suitable for the company searching for it
8. Recent posts - a company will be able to add an article to the forum, these should be able to track here.
9. A rating system! Functionality/Price/User friendlyness/Service level (in order to be able to  rate each company there needs to be a control system - either emailing us, logging in as a member, being forced to add name and contact number (thus making it possible for us to remove false identities)

I tried to upload images to help show ideas about what I mean but I didn't make it. I need the perfect code to do this! Who can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: *@Anna:* This forum is about finding solutions to problems that are of common nature. I read your question like a catalog created for a concrete project. This results in having multiple questions at once which is generally hard to answer. Please consider reducing your question to a more common scope.

Comment: *@hakre*: I'm a bit to blame for *@Anna* posting her laundry list here; she asked a much simpler question over at the LinkedIn WordPress group and I suggested she post here too. I guess since then she decided to collect up everything she wanted and post it all! :) I'm going to see if I can help her offline because, you are correct, this is not a question that can be answered because it's many different questions.

Comment: @Anna: I did an evaluation this summer trying to accomplish a lot of the functionality you had listed. I didn't find anything available all in one place. I ended up writing a custom solution that leveraged custom post types and taxonomies.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good starting point is to read through the answer to this question: 
[Implementing a CrunchBase.com clone using Wordpress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/381/implementing-a-crunchbase-com-clone-using-wordpress)

That does not cover all the problems you need help with but it's a start.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot - may I ask (and this might showcase my lack of deep programming knowledge) - where in the functions.php do I paste it?

Comment: I don't think it matters but I'm not sure. If you don't want to start editing the functions.php you can install a plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) and make custom post types and taxonomies from there.

Comment: *@Anna*: It doesn't matter where as long as it's not in the middle of some other function. Safest is to just add it to the very end.

Comment: Ooops, thank you all - I am new to this. I'll try and divide my question. The difficulty though it all being part of one category... Thanks Mike for explaining and of course you are right. I do though hope and believe that it sounds harder than it is?!

Answer (score 0):

You might also have a look at the 'Connections' plugin. Does most of what you want I think, and the plugin developer is willing to make enhancements.