# How to setup a membership system in Wordpress?

Tags: customization, categories, homepage, directory, membership

I have been setting up a wordpress for a business memberships, where the business sign up and list their company information to our site. Once they become a member their company listing and what they offer is supposed to be listed on in certain categories (which will be populated on the homepage).

I need to know how to create a membership page for sign up. So when the person signs up they are listed in a certain category that will be listed on the home page.

Hope I gave enough details on this matter. Im using version 3.0.3.

I would appreciate any help/advice.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question seems too broad and "please do it for me (for free)"-like IMHO.

Comment: You might be intereseted in this question as well: [Creating a searchable A-Z listing of hundreds of companies/services](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/creating-a-searchable-a-z-listing-of-hundreds-of-companies-services)

Answer (score 1):

There are hooks in wp-login.php that allow to set up a custom forms. You could use them to override the register and login screens as necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a better idea of what needs to be done and how to do it. I appreciate it.

Comment: @gdinari: Please write what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to go about this and they'd depend on the scope of the listings and your knowledge of Wordpress.  The simplest would be to install one of the numerous Business Directory plugins.  Some of them have a customizable front end registration form.

You could also set up a custom post type for a Business Listing with a custom taxonomy for the different organizational characteristics they will be defined by.  Then you could create come custom meta boxes on the post write screen where they would enter their business profile.

Comment: Great! I think this might be exactly what Im looking for. Im about to try these solutions now. Thanks a lot for your help!