# How to create a mini directory in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, directory

I'm looking to create a simple directory, something similar but not so powerful as [SOBI2 for Joomla](http://www.sigsiu.net/sobi2.html).

Is there something like this for Wordpress?

I want to store informations like:

- Name
- URL
- Address (country, region)
- Details (text)

People should be able to browse or search such a simple directory.

Is there something like this available for WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is to use **Custom Post Types** with custom fields to create your own directory.  Here's an answer I wrote about exactly that:

- [**Tips for using WordPress as a CMS?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187)
- [**Implementing a CrunchBase.com Clone using WordPress?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/381/implementing-a-crunchbase-com-clone-using-wordpress/386#386)

Also, take a look at the **SimpleFields** plugin for WordPress which can help you create these custom fields:

- [**SimpleFields Plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/)

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew about the custom post types. This does open a new worlds of opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

Had you looked at native Links (bookmarks) feature? Is it little under-hyped, but Links can be categorized, store decent amount of meta information and are quite easy to work with.

Otherwise you are looking at plugin area or custom fields (or custom post types, which is out of simple realm).

Posts on topic:

- [Using bookmarks more effectively ( Justin Tadlock )](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/12/18/using-bookmarks-more-effectively)
- [Make use of Links in WordPress ( Rarst )](http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-links/)

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to check out the [Business Directory WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/business-directory/screenshots/)

Comment: This looks promising but is still very simple and not customizable. For example it will display only a fix set of information and the categories usage is buggy. Now real support for filtering by location. Still is the closest solution I received so far.

Comment: In that case you may want to check out the Contact Manager theme from RoloPress. I came across it when searching for a CRM/contact manager that I could host internally. Haven't had a chance to play with it yet, but it looks promising and I've heard good things. Link: http://rolopress.com/