# Creating my own Admin Forms in a WordPress CMS?

Tags: customization, wp-admin, admin, cms, forms

I just decided to try using WordPress for a CMS (not a blog).  The site will have some product information that I want the client to be able to update.  Instead of creating an entire admin side just for them to update their products, is it possible to create a form in the WordPress admin so they can add products to a database?

Is changing the WordPress admin side good practice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely! That's exactly what I've been doing for months now. (*There are some [**screenshots**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187) here to show you what's possible.)* Just **create a Custom Post Type** for your their products, and then use a plugin to allow to you create **Custom Metaboxes** with fields. Here's a list to consider:

#### Plugins for Fields & Metaboxes

The plugin that I think is best at the moment is **Simple Fields** although I'd suggest you consider others:

- [**Simple Fields**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/)
- [**Easy Custom Fields**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-custom-fields/)
- [**Verve Meta Boxes**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/verve-meta-boxes/)
- [**Magic Fields**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields/) ([See Also](http://magicfields.org/))

#### Plugins for Defining Post Types

In addition you can simply define your custom post types with the `register_post_type()` function *(which is how I prefer to do it, for many reasons not to least of which is it is easier to version control them with Subversion or Git if you do)* or you can use one of these plugins which might be easier when you are new to custom post types:

- [**CMS Press**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-press/)
- [**Custom Post Type UI**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)
- [**WP Easy Post Types**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-post-types/) ([See Also](http://www.wpeasyposttypes.com/))
- [**WP Post Type UI**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-post-type-ui/)
- [**GD Custom Posts And Taxonomies Tools**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-taxonomies-tools/)
- [**Ultimate Post Type Manager**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-post-type-manager/)

**Note:** Some of these plugins may actually let you define fields too and some of the fields plugins I mentioned above may let you manage custom post types as well. I've not had the time to research them all so if I need to move these around or embellish on my description, please let me know.

#### Custom Post Type Archive Pages

You'll also want to create archive pages for custom post types which will show up as a feature of WordPress 3.1 but until then these plugins might be useful (though I've not tried them):

- [**Simple Custom Post Type Archives**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-custom-post-type-archives/)
- [**Custom Post Type Archives**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-archives/)

#### Learning More About Custom Post Types

There are getting to be a lot of references on custom post types, here are some I can suggest *(I wrote the first two as answers where on WA)*:

- **On StackExchange**

  - [**Tips for using WordPress as a CMS?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187)
  - [**Implementing a CrunchBase.com Clone using WordPress?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/381/implementing-a-crunchbase-com-clone-using-wordpress/386#386)
- **On WordPress Codex**

  - [**Custom Post Types**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Post_Types)
  - [**"Supports" Reference for Custom Post Types**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_supports)
- **Blog Posts**

  - [**Custom post types in WordPress**](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress)
  - [**101 Techniques for a Powerful CMS using WordPress**](http://www.noupe.com/wordpress/powerful-cms-using-wordpress.html)
  - [**Rock-Solid WordPress 3.0 Themes using Custom Post Types**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/rock-solid-wordpress-3-0-themes-using-custom-post-types/)
  - [**WordPress Custom Post Types And Taxonomies The Right Way**](http://new2wp.com/pro/wordpress-custom-post-types-and-taxonomies-done-right/)
  - [**Custom Post Types in WordPress 3.0**](http://kovshenin.com/archives/custom-post-types-in-wordpress-3-0/)
  - [**Adding Custom Field GUI to Custom Post Types in WordPress 3.0**](http://blog.genuineinteractive.com/post/adding-custom-field-gui-to-custom-post-types-wordpress-3.aspx)

And here's some notes from a presentation I gave on Custom Post Types to the Atlanta WordPress Meetup group recently:

- [**Presentation Notes: *Custom Post Types for WordPress***](http://files.meetup.com/1280797/custom-post-types-for-wordpress-atlwp-2010-10-24.html#links)

Comment: wow - pretty nice answer , if that doesn't help , i wonder what would , lol

Comment: Yes Mike thank you very much!  I have some reading to do :)