# Is there documentation reference for forms in menu and setting pages?

Tags: plugin-development, forms, customization, add-menu-page, add-submenu-page

Trying to stick to WordPress best practices and improving how I do plugin development I have searched through the codex and developer documentation to see if there is anything indicating what is preferred when developing forms in setting pages in regard to what HTML and CSS is used.  My goal is to improve how I develop my plugins and stick to what is already offered for developing a settings/menu page but when I search for a discussion or documentation on the topic I am clouded with:

- [Getting Started with WordPress Plugin Development: The Ultimate Guide](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-plugin-development-guide/) [form](https://gist.github.com/danielpataki/c0dd60f310eac47df91e#file-form-html) appears to be a generic form.
- [The Complete Guide To The WordPress Settings API, Part 3: All About Menus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-3-all-about-menus--wp-24749) is from 2012 and as the comments indicate it is no longer a valid approach to development.
- [Creating my own Admin Forms in a WordPress CMS?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3410/creating-my-own-admin-forms-in-a-wordpress-cms) only has an answer that directs people to plugins.
- When you reference the codex [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) the only coverage in regards to the form is at the bottom where it discusses securing your forms with nonces
- The [theme handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/plugin-api-hooks/) is limited on plugin forms
- When searching for plugin development I did run across [add_menu_page() with different name for first submenu item](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66498/add-menu-page-with-different-name-for-first-submenu-item) but that covers the menus not the forms
- Lastly when referencing the codex [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) and [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) I do not see a re-direct or mention what to do with forms.

Nothing official about the forms or if they should use WordPress's generic HTML and CSS implementation.  So does WordPress have any documentation or standards that exist for forms in the menus/settings pages or is it always going to be the discretion of the developer?

Comment: I just view the admin source and copy the structure from there.

Comment: I've done that as well but I would have thought based on everything else that has been included in the codex as "you should do this" it surprises me I dont see anything on forms

Comment: You could write it :-)

Comment: id be afraid to but I might make something on github.

Comment: Are you using the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)? Afaik it handles a lot of the frontend display as well

Comment: You're right @TimMalone I didn't spot the reference to settings in the question and most of my admin forms are for metadata on posts.