# posts and cms and posts again

Tags: posts, cms, blog

I'm setting up a WP site as a CMS that will sell CDs. I have set up the individual titles as posts on a page I call recordings, and have a number of categories that make up the collection of discs. I'm not sure if this is the best way to setup the site as a CMS, though.

Additionally, I want to set up another page for a blog under the "about us" section of the site. Is this possible, since I've already allocated the recordings page as the posts page?

Or can I just make a blog entry on the Posts page w/the category of Blog and call only those posts?

Is there a better way to make a 'recordings' database besides using the posts approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a 'recording' post type and leave posts for the blog section.

The "blog as category" approach would work too, but it's rather messy, I think.

Comment: Yes, this was on my 'to do list'. thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with @scribu but I'll elaborate by pointing you to a related set of answers:

- [**Tips for using WordPress as a CMS?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187)
- [**Implementing a CrunchBase.com Clone using WordPress?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/381/implementing-a-crunchbase-com-clone-using-wordpress/386#386)

Comment: Thank you as well, Mike--I've been reading up on CMS options and the topic of custom post types, and I've just added one as recordings. It's even sort of working, but as expected opened up a whole new can of worms that is too late to ask questions on tonight. Thanks again--this question alone had stalled me from moving forward.

Comment: @don de lion - Glad we could help.  Looking forward to those additional questions.