# Making Custom Fields Standard in the Admin UI

Tags: customization, custom-post-types, wp-admin, hooks

I've added a few different `custom_post_types` to my Wordpress 3 installation. They are all a bit different from eachother, and should store unique information in `custom_fields`. But while one may store a `product_id`, another will not. One will have a `source_url` and another will not. Rather than having to instruct my editors on which custom fields should be used with which custom posts, how can I make each custom post include its custom fields as part of the UI itself?

If you visit "daily_cartoon" you would have a screen that asks only for a *title*, *caption*, and *media*.
If you visit "daily_product" you would have a screen that asks only for a *title*, *price*, *summary*, etc.

Comment: *@Jonathan Sampson*: I'm working all weekend on a package to address this (I've been working on it for over a month.) But I have a deadline of Tuesday so no answering StackExchange questions for me this weekend. If this is still unresolved later next week I'll definitely address it.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I'm actually still working on the project, so if you finished your tool already I'd be more than happy to give it a spin and share my experience.

Comment: Hi *@Jonathan Sampson*: I'm not ready to publish it yet but I can work with you privately as my first beta tester if you like. Contact me via email, my email address is on my user profile page: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi **@Jonathan Sampson**:

There are **several plugins to make Custom Post Types easier** and some allow you to define Custom Fields too, in no particular order:

- [**WP Easy Post Types**](http://www.wpeasyposttypes.com/)
- [**GD Custom Posts And Taxonomies Tools**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-taxonomies-tools/)
- [**Custom Post Type UI**](http://www.strangework.com/wordpress-plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)
- [**Simple Fields**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/)

As I mentioned above I've been working on one that does not provide a User Interface like these to instead an extensible API for complex field types (and simple ones too.) But after spending an hour trying to package it I realized it's not ready for distribution yet. Maybe in a few weeks.

These plugins listed above should meet your basic needs for now and I will try to make mine compatible with the data stored by all of these in the future in case you do decided to use mine in the future.

You also might find this post a bit of help too:

- [**Tips for using WordPress as a CMS?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187)

Comment: I'll mark fave this question and will wait your solution ;)

Comment: *@silent*: Cool!

Answer (score 5):

you can add  meta_boxes in order to have the custom fields data stored in them.
since [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) can be set according to post_type this will enable you to add different meta_box to different post types.

look at this [post](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-metabox-custom-post-type) for a full example of altering  the custom post type new/edit scree.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently needed to address a very similar problem while working within a theme.  The basis of the code was from this [post](http://devaldez.com/how-to-make-wp-custom-fields-better/) and I had modified some of the code

The following is the first portion of the code I had modified.

```
    add_action('init', 'limited_post_type');
function my_custom_limited_post_type() 
{
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Limited Post Type', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Film - DVD', 'post type singular name')
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt', 'page-attributes','custom-fields' ),
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true
  ); 
  register_post_type('limited_post_type', $args);
}
```

The following is the second portion of the code I had modified.

```
foreach ( $scope as $scopeItem ) {
       switch ( $scopeItem ) {
           case "post": {
             // Output on any post screen
             if ( basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] )=="post-new.php" || $post->post_type=="post" )
             $output = true;
             break;}              
            case "page": {
                  // Output on any page screen
                  if ( basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] )=="page-new.php" || $post->post_type=="page" )
            $output = true;
            break;}
             case "limited_post_type": {
                                // Output on limited post_type onlye
            if ((basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] )=="post-new.php" && $post->post_type=="limited_post_type" ) || (basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] )=="post.php" && $post->post_type=="film_dvd" ))
                   $output = true;
                   break;
                  }
```

If you like please send me a message and I will gladly send you my functions.php file for your reference.  This is definitely the way to make it happen though as I went through many nights of hair pulling as yourself.