# Custom post types - remove default post supports through empty array?

Tags: plugins, customization, plugin-development

I recently asked a [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/redesigning-custom-post-type-add-new-page) the other day and got what I was looking for. Today I put that knowledge to practice, but I can't seem to figure how to remove the title and editor fields from the "edit" page.

Below shows the arguments I'm using with `register_post_type`. Logically, I think providing an empty array for "supports" would make it not support anything by default. Am I missing something?

```
        $v_args = array(
                'labels' => array (
                        'name' => 'Visitors',
                        'singular_name' => 'Visitor',
                        'add_new_item' => 'Register New Visitor',
                    ),
                'public' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => false,
                'exclude_from_search' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'hiearchical' => false,
                'supports' => array( ),
            );
```

Thanks,
-Zack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close .) This works:

```
'supports' => array( '' ),
```

Comment: I knew I was going to slap myself when the answer came. Thank you ;)

Comment: The trick is that you need to get past `empty()`. Just `array()` won't work, but `array( '' )` will.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something in there. Title & Editor are the **defaults when nothing is present**, so adding something may remove those two (though I've never tested it), i.e.:

'author'
'thumbnail'
'excerpt'
'trackbacks'
'custom-fields'
'comments'
'revisions'
'page-attributes'