# Updating post meta for custom post types

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, customization, plugin-development, post-meta

I'm writing a plugin for work (still) and having one more issue.

I've added my meta boxes as needed. However, the problem I'm having occurs when *saving* the post. My snippets for saving pretty much come from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434327/wordpress-update-post-meta-values-delete-when-empty-or-just-test-for). I've also recieved a similar answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/redesigning-custom-post-type-add-new-page/6575#6575), but it's just not working for some reason. :/

```
  protected function __update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value = '' )
  {
   if ( empty( $value ) OR ! $value )
   {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name );
   }
   elseif ( ! get_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name ) )
   {
    add_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value );
   }
   else
   {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value );
   }
  }
```

The above is called using the following. However, I'm not sure my problem lies with the actual saving now that I think of it. I'm thinking it might be the `nonce` which may be throwing it off.

```
  public function _wp_save_post( $post_id, $post )
  {
   if ( empty($_POST)
     OR !isset($_POST['argus_edit_visitor'])
     OR !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['argus_edit_visitor'], 'argus_edit_visitor' ) )
   {
    return $post->ID;
   }

   if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ) ) return $post->ID;

   // v_f_name | v_l_name | v_workstation | v_id
   // Argh!

   $this->__update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'v_f_name', $_POST['v_f_name'] );
   $this->__update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'v_l_name', $_POST['v_l_name'] );
   $this->__update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'v_workstation', $_POST['v_workstation'] );
   $this->__update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'v_id', $_POST['v_id'] );
  }
```

The nonce is used like the following: `<input type="hidden" name="argus_edit_visitor" id="argus_edit_visitor" value="{$nonce}" />` and created using `$nonce = wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );`. The input field is inside block of html being stored in variable $html. Stackexchange was parsing my html otherwise I'd paste it here.

-Zack

**EDIT:** Just tested it, and it **is** the nonce's fault.
**EDIT2:** Typo on my part, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please drop your entire code in a pastebin so we can see the entire class?  I think you're right that's it's the nonce ... but I'll need to see everything in context to be sure.

Comment: @EAMann: Yea sure. Here it is -> http://pastebin.com/ucNrB0jF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like your clean class structure :-)  But I have a suggestion that might fix things (based on my experience with nonces and meta boxes from a plug-in I built last weekend):

**Don't try to create the nonce field manually.**  You currently have:

```
$nonce = wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );

...

<input type="hidden" name="argus_edit_visitor" id="argus_edit_visitor" value="{$nonce}" />
```

The standard way to create this field is using WordPress' `wp_nonce_field()` function.  It will add the hidden field for you:

```
wp_nonce_field( __FILE__, 'argus_edit_visitor' );
```

**Verifying the nonce**

You're verifying against the wrong string.  In your code, you created the nonce with `__FILE__` but you verify with the string `argus_edit_vistor`.  You have:

```
if ( empty($_POST)
    OR !isset($_POST['argus_edit_visitor'])
    OR !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['argus_edit_visitor'], 'argus_edit_visitor' ) )
    {
        echo "Erm. Why?";
        return $post->ID;
    }
```

You should have:

```
if ( empty($_POST)
    OR !isset($_POST['argus_edit_visitor'])
    OR !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['argus_edit_visitor'], __FILE__ ) )
    {
        echo "Erm. Why?";
        return $post->ID;
    }
```

I usually use `plugin_basename(__FILE__)` when creating nonces.  But you shouldn't run into problems doing it your way so long as the nonce creation and nonce verification happens in the same file.

Comment: awesome, completely awesome. Thanks about the class structure, too. :-)