# Custom Field as Custom Taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, customization

I have a custom taxonomy, "Country". I am using WP User Frontend to let users post to the site. Most data is saved as custom fields, so I have a custom field "cf_country". I want to be able to set that custom field to the taxonomy for existing and all future posts. I found a converter plugin, but its a one time thing. I want this to happen automatically. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

**Possible Solution**
    `function save_taxonomy_data( $post_id ) {

```
// verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization.
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'wpuf-add-post' ) ) 
    return;

// OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
if ( isset( $_POST['cf_country'] ) ) { 
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $_POST['cf_country'], 'country' );
}
}
add_action('wpuf_add_post_after_insert', 'save_taxonomy_data');
function edit_taxonomy_data( $post_id ) {

// verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization.
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'wpuf-edit-post' ) ) 
    return;

// OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
if ( isset( $_POST['cf_country'] ) ) { 
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $_POST['cf_country'], 'country' );
}
}
add_action('save_post', 'edit_taxonomy_data');`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how your input form looks, I can only give you the following as a suggestion.  Basically you verify that you want/have permission to save the data and then take the meta's input and set it as a term in your taxonomy via [`wp_set_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms).  You'll want to fire this every time a post is saved... ie on the `save_post` hook.

```
function save_taxonomy_data($post_id) {

    // verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization.
    // your form should have a nonce <?php wp_nonce_field('taxonomy_country','taxonomy_noncename'); ?>
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['taxonomy_noncename'], 'taxonomy_country' )) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // verify if this is an auto save routine. If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return $post_id;


    // Check permissions
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;
    } else {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
    }

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    // right now it is only working on posts and pages, need to adapt to other types here
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ( ($post->post_type == 'post') || ($post->post_type == 'page') ) { 

        isset( $_POST['post_country'] )
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $_POST['post_country'], 'country' );

    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'save_taxonomy_data');
```

Adapted from [Custom Taxonomy Panels](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-input-panels) and also similar to [Unable to save custom taxonomy terms in a custom-built metabox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9015/unable-to-save-custom-taxonomy-terms-in-a-custom-built-metabox).

**Second Attempt**

The first attempt is pretty much how to save taxonomy data from a metabox.  I took a glance at the WP User Frontend code and made a few adjustments.  This is intended to replace what was above, and assumes that *cf_country* is the name element of the input.

```
function save_taxonomy_data( $post_id ) {

    // verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'wpuf-add-post' ) ) 
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf_country'] ) ) { 
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $_POST['cf_country'], 'country' );
    }

}
add_action('wpuf_add_post_after_insert', 'save_taxonomy_data');
```

**Third Attempt:**

```
function save_taxonomy_data($post_id) {

    /* 
     * verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization.
    * your form should have a nonce <?php wp_nonce_field('wpuf-add-post','_wpnonce'); ?>
    */
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'wpuf-add-post' )) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // verify if this is an auto save routine. If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return $post_id;


    // Check permissions
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['wpuf_post_type'] ) { // post type is a hidden field in wpuf_
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;
    } else {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Work on all post types
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_country'] ) ) 
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $_POST['post_country'], 'country' );


}
add_action('save_post', 'save_taxonomy_data');
```

Comment: Here is the .php that controls the form input (http://pastebin.com/0VF0Q4tj). Hopefully that helps.

As for your script, where would I add it? In my functions.php or elsewhere? I am unfamiliar with the save_post hook so a little guidance would be very appreciated!

Comment: I added your script to my functions.php but it just stopped my site from working. Am I missing something?

Comment: "Stopped your site from working"... how exactly? Enable [wp_debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG) to get a useful message. I don't see any blatant punctuation errors, but that doesn't mean they aren't there.  And this isn't guaranteed to work with your form specifically, it is more of a guideline on how to save taxonomy info.  Finally looking at your code, there is this hook `wpuf_add_post_after_insert` which might be worth using in lieu of `save_post`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. It works, perfectly. It seems so simple, too. Thanks.

Comment: Cool!  Glad it worked, I Wasn't sure since I am not using your plugin and couldn't test it.

Comment: One last question. What about if the user updates their post and changes the country? Would "wpuf_edit_post_after_insert" work? Where in the code would it go?

Comment: You'd run the same function on the other hook too.  `add_action('wpuf_edit_post_after_insert', 'save_taxonomy_data');`  Though you might only need to combine them both to `add_action('save_post', 'save_taxonomy_data');` though the `wpuf_` functions go through their own error checking process.  I don't like how I don't have all the same checks as in version 1 (which I think I found the error in- a bad comment character )

Comment: See my third attempt? If that fails, then just do what I recommended at the beginning of the previous comment.

Comment: `function edit_taxonomy_data( $post_id ) {

    // verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'wpuf-edit-post' ) ) 
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf_country'] ) ) { 
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $_POST['cf_country'], 'country' );
    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'edit_taxonomy_data');`

Comment: This seemed to work. It was added after Attempt 2. Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: Can you post it as an edit to your question?  It is hard to read in the comments.