# Add custom field automatically to custom page types

Tags: theme-development

I have a custom page type set up called 'Products' and I need each of these post to automatically have multiple custom fields to set up a table of features/prices for the individual product pages.

Is there any way this can be done? Thanks.

Comment: Sure it's possible. Are you just wanting "placeholder" custom fields, i.e. with blank values?

Comment: I think he means custom meta boxes?

Comment: Jared check out the "More Fields" plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/ ... it basically extends the existing custom field functionality into something a little more useful(give it a shot)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had a question about this. Luckily, [Chris_O](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/redesigning-custom-post-type-add-new-page/6575#6575) answered it for me. You may also want to check out [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms), too.

Here's an example of what I've done with meta boxes and you can see it's quite easy.

[image: Example Post Type]

Answer (score 2):

Using custom fields on custom post types is a pretty common task. What you essentialy need to do is adding a metabox and saving the values to the database.  There already are some pretty good explanations of how to achieve what you want to do.

You should check out the official documentation of [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), there's a fully working example in there!

― André

Comment: He said page types, not post types.