# How to do admin CRUD & Pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I am wondering how might I create an admin page to do CRUD. I know how to add a basic/options page to the admin menu. But I want to go further, how might I manage data (CRUD) and for the index/listing page, I will need pagination, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do CRUD in WordPress for probably 99% of use-cases is to create a [**Custom Post Type**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187). CPTs will give you CRUD almost for free, then after that you may need to ask a few more questions here about how to do selected additional things, depending on your specific use-case. Good luck!

Comment: I know abt custom post type, but currently I have a plugin for newsletters so users can signup with their name+email which does not seem to fit well in a post (I will have a empty post and store name/email in custom fields?)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with coding up some classes.

Credits: http://design.sparklette.net/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/

On 2nd thought very long but works... if anyone improves it, it will be great to add a link in comments :)

```
class Pager {
    protected $table;
    protected $pages;
    protected $perpage;
    protected $page;
    protected $wpdb;
    protected $otherSQL;

    public function __construct($table, $perpage, $page, $otherSQL = '') {
        global $wpdb;
        $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
        $this->table = $wpdb->prefix . $table;
        $this->perpage = $perpage;
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->pages = ceil($wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $this->table) / $this->perpage);
        $this->otherSQL = $otherSQL;
    }

    protected function getFirstPageURL() {
        return UrlUtils::appendQueryString('pagenum', 1);
    }

    protected function getPrevPageURL() {
        return UrlUtils::appendQueryString('pagenum', $this->page == 1 ? 1 : $this->pagenum - 1);
    }

    protected function getNextPageURL() {
        return UrlUtils::appendQueryString('pagenum', $this->page == $this->pages ? $this->pages : $this->page + 1);
    }

    protected function getLastPageURL() {
        return UrlUtils::appendQueryString('pagenum', $this->pages);
    }

    protected function getPageURL($page) {
        return UrlUtils::appendQueryString('pagenum', $page);
    }

    public function generatePagination($range = 2) {
        $shown = $range * 2 + 1;
        ?>
        <div class="tablenav">
            <div class="tablenav-pages">
                <span class="displaying-num"><?php echo $this->pages; ?> page(s)</span>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getFirstPageURL(); ?>" <?php if ($this->page == 1) echo 'class="disabled"';  ?>>&laquo;</a>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getPrevPageURL(); ?>" <?php if ($this->page == 1) echo 'class="disabled"';  ?>>&lsaquo;</a> 

                <?php
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $this->pages; $i++) { 
                    if ($this->pages != 1 &&( !($i >= $this->pages + $shown || $i <= $this->page - $shown) || $this->pages <= $shown )) {
                        echo '<a href="' . $this->getPageURL($i) . '" ' . ($i == $this->page ? 'class="disabled"' : '' ) . '>' . $i . '</a>';
                    }
                }
                ?>

                <a href="<?php echo $this->getNextPageURL(); ?>" <?php if ($this->page == $this->pages) echo 'class="disabled"';  ?>>&raquo;</a>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getLastPageURL(); ?>" <?php if ($this->page == $this->pages) echo 'class="disabled"';  ?>>&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    public function getPageData() {
        $data = $this->wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $this->table . ' ' . $this->otherSQL . ' LIMIT ' . ($this->page - 1) * $this->perpage . ', ' . $this->perpage, OBJECT );
        return $data;
    }

}

class UrlUtils {

    public static function parseQueryString($url = '') {
        $queryArr = array();
        $queryStr = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        if (!empty($url)) {
            $queryStr = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        }
        parse_str($queryStr, $queryArr);
        return $queryArr;
    }

    public static function appendQueryString($key, $val, $url = "") {
        $queryArr = self::parseQueryString($url);
        $queryArr[$key] = $val;
        $queryStr = http_build_query($queryArr);

        $url = empty($url) ? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] : $url;
        $parts = parse_url($url);
        $parts['query'] = $queryStr;

        return $parts['path'] . '?' . $parts['query'];
    }

    public static function removeQueryString($remove) {
        $queryArr = self::parseQueryString();
        if (is_array($remove)) {
            foreach ($remove as  $r) {
                if (array_key_exists($r, $queryArr)) {
                    unset($queryArr[$r]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (array_key_exists($remove, $queryArr)) {
                unset($queryArr[$remove]);
            }
        }

        $queryStr = http_build_query($queryArr);
        return $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $queryStr;
    }

}

// Usage like

require_once('inc/pager.php');
$pager = new Pager('km_contact', 20, (isset($_GET['pagenum']) && is_numeric($_GET['pagenum'])) ? $_GET['pagenum'] : 1, 'ORDER BY dt DESC');
$contacts = $pager->getPageData();

...

<?php foreach ($contacts as $c) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $c->name; ?></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:<?php echo $c->name; ?>"><?php echo $c->email; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $c->subject; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $c->content; ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo UrlUtils::appendQueryString('viewid', $c->id); ?>">View</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
...

$pager->generatePagination();
```