# How do I create a custom post type for a training CMS in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, page-template, cms

I need to create a custom post type based on the existing 'Page' type, for a WordPress based training CMS. I have no problem simply creating a new post type, but I would like to offer some kind of templating in these training pages for the inclusion of standard, repeated content such as instructions, as well as the possible inclusion of simple multiple choice tests in each page type. How can I go about this? What areas of the Codex should I be studying?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link which might Help you to create custom content types.(includes codex you need to Learn )

[The WordPress Codex on Custom Post Types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms)

For More Links on creating custom content type [visit this Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms)