# Create Custom Admin Fields

Tags: customization, wp-admin

I'm looking to create custom admin options/menu/fields (I'm not positive on the correct terminology) and would like some guidance. I found a post here which does speak about it in the answer:
[Tips for using WordPress as a CMS?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms)

I would like to create a field like the 'Attorneys' menu shown in @MikeSchinkel 's answer.

If you know a page that has instructions on best practise to create this could you please link me?

I have searched the net for hours on end for a solution and the best I came up with is the 'Custom Post Type UI' (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin which does not give me the flexibility I need.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Recommendation of plugins or themes or anything such is beyond the scope of this community. Please check [how to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what not to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Now please edit the question accordingly for seeking help from the community.

Comment: @MarutiMohanty I hope the changes bring it into the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and [Pods](http://pods.io/) are plugins that both deal with custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create your own custom post type with a generator like this.
http://generatewp.com/post-type/

Answer (score 0):

i agree with `wrought_steel` i too use this `http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/` plugin. And here is its documentation for more help. `http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/`